# Best way to deal with dollar character in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following class `PlaceHolderConverter` used to parse string like `"my {} are beautiful"` into strings with filled variables.

For instance `new PlaceHolderConverter("\\{\\}").format("my {} are beautiful", "flowers")` will return the string `"my flowers are beautiful"`.

```java
package something;


import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PlaceHolderConverter
{
    public Pattern lookForVar;

    public PlaceHolderConverter( String placeHolder )
    {
        this.lookForVar = Pattern.compile( placeHolder );
    }

    public String format( String text, String... args )
    {
        if ( args == null || args.length == 0 )
        {
            return text;
        }
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher matcher = lookForVar.matcher( text );
        short varCount = 0;
        while ( matcher.find() )
        {
            matcher.appendReplacement( stringBuffer, args[varCount++] );
        }
        matcher.appendTail( stringBuffer );
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the following tests, I have issue with the special character dollar because it's a special character for java regex.
I tried to solve that with `Pattern.quote()` but without results.

```java
package something;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PlaceHolderConverterTest
{
    private PlaceHolderConverter placeHolderConverter;

    @Before
    public void before()
    {
        placeHolderConverter = new PlaceHolderConverter( "\\{\\}" );
    }

    @Test // SUCCESS
    public void whenStringArgsThenReplace()
    {
        String result = placeHolderConverter.format( "My {} are beautifull", "flowers" );
        Assert.assertEquals( "My flowers are beautifull", result );
    }

    @Test // FAIL IllegalArgumentException illegal group reference while calling appendReplacement
    public void assertEscapeDollar()
    {
        String result = placeHolderConverter.format( "My {} are beautiful", "flow$ers" );
        Assert.assertEquals( "My flow$ers are beautiful", result );
    }

    @Test // FAIL IllegalArgumentException illegal group reference while calling appendReplacement
    public void assertEscapeDollarWithQuote()
    {
        String result = placeHolderConverter.format( "My {} are beautiful", Pattern.quote("flow$ers") );
        Assert.assertEquals( "My flow$ers are beautiful", result );
    }

}
```

I also to tried to manually escape the dollar before using it in regexp, with something like `.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\$")` but it seems that `replaceAll` dislike to have to arg1 included in arg2.

How I can fix that ?

Patch can be provided here https://gist.github.com/3937872

Comment: Use a simple `replace` function to replace fixed strings: `s.replace("$", "\\$");`

Comment: And when the string has multiple dollars ?

Comment: One call is still enough. Check out the Javadoc and try it out.

Comment: You can replace `$` with `\\$` or using square brackets `[$]`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I couldn't find `replace(String, String)`, just `replace(char, char)`. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @OlafDietsche I mean `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`. This seems to confuse a lot of people and cause them to ignore this method.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I erroneously looked into 1.4, where this doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik oups you are right, `replace()` do the job, even if there is more than one occurence of dollar ! Thanks for the help, maybe you can add it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When replacing a fixed string, there is no need to call the regex methods on String because there is a simpler one: `input.replace("$", "\\$");`. With this method you won't have any of the troubles caused by the special meaning of the dollar sign, and it will be (very slightly) faster as a bonus.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation why `Pattern.quote()` fails:

`Pattern.quote()` is designed to be used on regular expressions (meaning *search* expressions). It works by surrounding the string with `"\\Q"` and `"\\E"`, which mean "Start of verbatim section" and "End of verbatim section", respectively.

Your error results from an unescaped `$` in your *replacement*  string, which is not a regex and therefore can't be correctly escaped using `Pattern.quote()`. Therefore, the correct solution is to escape the dollar sign manually in your replacement strings:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$");
```

or (since you don't need a regex at all for single character replaces) by using

```
String resultString = subjectString.replace("$", "\\$");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple solution, which covers your test cases:

```
public static String replace( String str, String placeholderRegex, Object... args ) {
    String repl = str.replaceAll( placeholderRegex, "%s" );
    return String.format( repl, args );
}
```

Lets check it:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.out.println( 
            replace( "my {} are beautifull {} test", 
                     "\\{\\}", 
                     "flowers", "$dollar" ) );
}
```

But, of course, if you have to deal with `%` chars, you'll have to modify function `replace` a bit (escape `%` before replacement, and unescape after). Also you may use pre-compiled regexps (as in your solution).

Comment: Damned you've just divided my code lines by 5... Nice tip to replace the placeHolder by `"%s"`

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you can let Java escape '$' signs for you (as others special characters like '\') in any replacement sequence of your like. This way you can still use String.replaceAll() if you wish.

```
String s = "input".replaceAll("pattern", Matcher.quoteReplacement("replacement"));
```

[(See Java Doc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String))